# How did 18th-century gubernatorial elections in Vermont compare to similar elections in other states?

Tags: united-states, 18th-century, election

In an disorganized way I have been reading various things about the 18th-century history of Vermont and I wondered whether their way of choosing and installing governors was unique, or the same as what was done in other states, or to what degree it was similar.

Both during Vermont's years as an independent country and during the years immediately following, elections for legislators and for governor were held each year in October.  Then the legislators assembled in whichever town was serving that year as the place where they meet.  The governor whose one-year term was about to end presided over the opening of the legislative session.  The legislature's first order of business was to count the votes for governor.  That took all day.  When the total was known, if one candidate out-polled all others combined, then that person, if present, got sworn in as governor and then presided over the rest of the legislature's session.  If no one had a majority (as happened in 1789) then the legislature chose someone to serve as governor.  Apparently the governor's term did not end on a pre-specified calendar date, but rather whenever the process of electing his successor was complete and the successor was sworn in.  If the successor was not present (as happened in 1790) then the outgoing governor continued to preside until his arrival.

**My question is to what extent all this resembled or did not resemble the processes used in other states?**

(To clear away possible confusions, I should add that Thomas Chittenden was elected every October from 1778 through 1788, and then again from 1790 to 1796.  He died in August 1797 with about seven weeks left of his term.  Moses Robinson was governor from October 1789 to October 1790.  Vermont's admission to the Union on March 4, 1791 happened during Chittenden's first term after his comeback.  Vermont's admission did not interrupt his term, nor those of any other officers of the state; the 1786 Constitution of Vermont simply continued in effect.) (Chittenden was also elected in March 1778 as the first-ever governor of Vermont, it having been decided that thereafter legislative sessions, and therefore governors' terms, would begin in October.)

Comment: You can read about Kentucky here: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Shelby#First_term_as_governor), election of 1791.  Wikipedia has lists of governors, by state; some of the governors listed have articles which describe their elections.